# Shortcut Keys in Java

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, system-tray

How could I (for example) maximize the window from tray icon when a specified key combination is pressed?

**edit:** So how can I detect for example when user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use some GUI event to detect the keyboard presses and the JNI (Java Native Interface) to maximize the window.

Look [at this example](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5208366) about JNI and window maximization. You should look [the guide of JNI](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/) too.